# How to filter out the required data from the xml sent by the server?

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest, xml-serialization

I want to get the data that is sent in xml by the server. I have read about xml parser but the data comes in xml and under that xml the data is in string form , that that is wrap up in data table. So here are many fields  tell me how to get each field separately?

response from server is :

```
    <<Table>
<CallDetailId>06012015192014733680011</CallDetailId>
<CallID>83A26D3811000100</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2015-01-06 19:20:14</CallDate>
<CalledBy>337</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>368</CalledTo>
<IsExternal>false</IsExternal>
<RecorderType>PRIMARY</RecorderType>
<FirstName />
<LastName />
<Comments />
<FlagID>1</FlagID>
<FlagImage>1.gif</FlagImage>
<CallDirection>I</CallDirection>
<FLAGTEXT>Training required</FLAGTEXT>
<Archive>true</Archive>
<ExtensionValue>368</ExtensionValue>
</Table>
<Table>
<AgentHangup>true</AgentHangup>
<CallDetailId>060120151424080020030003</CallDetailId>
<CallID>1F5D6D3803000100</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<CallDuration>5</CallDuration>
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2015-01-06 14:24:08</CallDate>
<CalledBy>2003</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>210</CalledTo>
<IsExternal>false</IsExternal>
<RecorderType>PRIMARY</RecorderType>
<FirstName />
<LastName />
<Comments />
<FlagID>1</FlagID>
<FlagImage>1.gif</FlagImage>
<AF>C:\Program Files (x86)\Alcatel-Lucent\OmniPCXRecord Suite\OmniPCXRecord\OmniPCXRECORDAudio\Repository\from\150106\0207\202_06012015 142408003_0003_2003.wav</AF>
<CallDirection>O</CallDirection>
<FLAGTEXT>Training required</FLAGTEXT>
<Archive>false</Archive>
<ExtensionValue>2003</ExtensionValue>
<GraphValue />
</Table>
<Table>
<AgentHangup>false</AgentHangup>
<CallDetailId>06012015142407832100003</CallDetailId>
<CallID>1F5D6D3803000100</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<CallDuration>5</CallDuration>
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2015-01-06 14:24:07</CallDate>
<CalledBy>2003</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>210</CalledTo>
<IsExternal>false</IsExternal>
<RecorderType>PRIMARY</RecorderType>
<FirstName />
<LastName />
<Comments />
<FlagID>1</FlagID>
<FlagImage>1.gif</FlagImage>
<AF>C:\Program Files (x86)\Alcatel-Lucent\OmniPCXRecord Suite\OmniPCXRecord\OmniPCXRECORDAudio\Repository\from\150106\0208\201_06012015 142407863_0003_210.wav</AF>
<CallDirection>I</CallDirection>
<FLAGTEXT>Training required</FLAGTEXT>
<Archive>false</Archive>
<ExtensionValue>210</ExtensionValue>
<GraphValue />
</Table>
<Table>
<CallDetailId>06012015141513152100001</CallDetailId>
<CallID>095B6D3801000100</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2015-01-06 14:15:13</CallDate>
<CalledBy>2003</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>210</CalledTo>
<IsExternal>false</IsExternal>
<RecorderType>PRIMARY</RecorderType>
<FirstName />
<LastName />
<Comments />
<FlagID>1</FlagID>
<FlagImage>1.gif</FlagImage>
<CallDirection>I</CallDirection>
<FLAGTEXT>Training required</FLAGTEXT>
<Archive>true</Archive>
<ExtensionValue>210</ExtensionValue>
</Table>
<Table>
<CallDetailId>060120151415133220030001</CallDetailId>
<CallID>095B6D3801000100</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2015-01-06 14:15:13</CallDate>
<CalledBy>2003</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>210</CalledTo>
<IsExternal>false</IsExternal>
<RecorderType>PRIMARY</RecorderType>
<FirstName />
<LastName />
<Comments />
<FlagID>1</FlagID>
<FlagImage>1.gif</FlagImage>
<CallDirection>O</CallDirection>
<FLAGTEXT>Training required</FLAGTEXT>
<Archive>true</Archive>
<ExtensionValue>2003</ExtensionValue>
</Table>
<Table>
<AgentHangup>false</AgentHangup>
<CallDetailId>101</CallDetailId>
<CallID>CAC4FB4F84DF0400</CallID>
<CorrelatorId />
<CallDuration>40</CallDuration>
<EncryptedCall>false</EncryptedCall>
<CallDate>2014/12/30 08:59:52</CallDate>
<CalledBy>02164714913</CalledBy>
<CalledTo>79100</CalledTo>
<FirstName>Omair</FirstName>
<LastName>Imran</LastName>
<Comments>N/A</Comments>
```

and I have to show the data in [this](http://postimg.org/image/pn1nzejlf/) form. In the data above each table is a compete row that I have to show in a table and not all fields in the table is compulsory to show in application just selected fields . So tell me How to do this

this is a code which I am using in main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView txt;
    private String celsius, results1,tweek;
    String status;
    public EditText edt;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.value_to_convert);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.convert);
        txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new DownLoadFromServer().execute();

            }
        });
    }



    private class DownLoadFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String resultsAfterBackground) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {


                edt.setText("" + tweek);
                //Log.v("Status",status);
                txt.setText("" + resultsAfterBackground);

                //edt.setText(celsius);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }


        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String Error = null;
            String resultsAfterBackground = null;
            try {
                SoapRequests ex = new SoapRequests();
                celsius = ex.getData("");

                Log.v("DataSet", "" + "Here is Data" + celsius);
                Integer checkErrorStatus = 7;


                    String results = celsius;

                    Document dom = null;
                    DocumentBuilder builder;
                    DocumentBuilderFactory factory;
                    try {
                        InputStream resultStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(results.getBytes("utf-8"));
                        factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                        dom = builder.parse(resultStream);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (SAXException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (dom != null) {
                        Log.v("Dom is Not Null", dom.toString() + "");
                        NodeList nodeList = dom.getElementsByTagName("NewDataSet");
                        Log.v("NodeList",nodeList.toString()+nodeList.getLength());
                        for (int itr = 0; itr < nodeList.getLength(); itr++) {
                            Node node = nodeList.item(itr);
                            if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                                Element eElement = (Element) node;
                                Log.v("Report of status of Element", eElement.toString());

                                   // String result1;


                               //results1 = eElement.getElementsByTagName("Table").item(1).getTextContent();
                                for (int j =0 ; j<=nodeList.getLength();j++){

                                    results1 =eElement.getElementsByTagName("Table").item(j).getTextContent();


                                }


                                tweek = eElement.getAttribute("CallDetailId");
                                 Log.v("Report of status", results1.toString());
                                resultsAfterBackground = results1;

                            }
                        }
                    }
//                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
//                    pDialog.setMessage("Connection Error");
                String string = e.toString();
                Log.v("Error", string);
              //  pDialog.dismiss();
            }

//            Log.v("BackResult",resultsAfterBackground);
            return resultsAfterBackground;


        }


    }


}
```

and here is my class for posting a request

```
public class SoapRequests {

private static final boolean DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE = true;
private static final String MAIN_REQUEST_URL = "My_Url"
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String SESSION_ID;
public static String Toaster=null ;

private final void testHttpResponse(HttpTransportSE ht) {
    ht.debug = DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE;
    if (DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE) {
        Log.v("SOAP RETURN", "Request XML:\n" + ht.requestDump);
        Log.v("SOAP RETURN", "\n\n\nResponse XML:\n" + ht.responseDump)
        ;
        Toaster=ht.responseDump;
    }
}

public String getData(String fValue) {
    String data = null;
    String methodname = "SearchCalls";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodname);
    //3
    request.addProperty("username", "admin");
    //
    request.addProperty("password", "admin");

    //5
    request.addProperty("FirstNameCriteria", "");
    //6
    request.addProperty("FirstName", "");
    //7
    request.addProperty("LastNameCriteria", "");
    //8
    request.addProperty("LastName", "");
    //9
    request.addProperty("GroupSearchOption", "");
    //10
    request.addProperty("GroupName", "");
    //11
    request.addProperty("EncryptedCallsCriteria", "");
    //12
    request.addProperty("AssociatedAgentCriteria", "");
    //13
    request.addProperty("CalledByCriteria", "");
    //14
    request.addProperty("CalledBy", "");
    //15
    request.addProperty("CalledToCriteria", "");
    //16
    request.addProperty("CalledTo", "");
    //17
    request.addProperty("CalledDateSearchCriteria", "Past_N_days");
    //18
    request.addProperty("NumberOfDays", "777");
    //19
    request.addProperty("StartDate", "");
    //20
    request.addProperty("EndDate", "");
    //21
    request.addProperty("CallDurationCriteria", "");
    //22
    request.addProperty("CallDuration", "");
    //23
    request.addProperty("CallDirectionCriteria", "");
    //24
    request.addProperty("ArchivedCallsCriteria", "");
    //25
    request.addProperty("ScreenCaptureCallsCriteria", "");
    //26
    request.addProperty("DeviceHangUpCriteria", "");
    //27
    request.addProperty("CallIDSearchCriteria", "");
    //28
    request.addProperty("CallID", "");
    //29
    request.addProperty("CorrelatorIDSearchCriteria", "");
    //30
    request.addProperty("CorrelatorID", "");
    //31
    request.addProperty("DeviceSearchCriteria", "");
    //32
    request.addProperty("Device", "");
    //33
    request.addProperty("FlagSearchCriteria", "All");
    //34
    request.addProperty("NotesSearchCriteria", "");
    //35
    request.addProperty("Notes", "");
    //36
    request.addProperty("CallStatus", "");
    //37
    request.addProperty("CallTypeSearchCriteria", "");
    //38
    request.addProperty("CustomField1_Criteria", "");
    //39
    request.addProperty("CustomFiled1_Value", "");
    //40
    request.addProperty("CustomField2_Criteria", "");
    //41
    request.addProperty("CustomField2_Value", "");
    //42
    request.addProperty("CustomField3_Criteria", "");
    //43
    request.addProperty("CustomField3_Value", "");
    //44
    request.addProperty("CustomField4_Criteria", "");
    //45
    request.addProperty("CustomField4_Value", "");
    //46
    request.addProperty("CustomField5_Criteria", "");
    //47
    request.addProperty("CustomField5_Value", "");
    //48
    request.addProperty("CustomField6_Criteria", "");
    //49
    request.addProperty("CustomField6_Value", "");
    //50
    request.addProperty("CustomField7_Criteria", "");
    //51
    request.addProperty("CustomField7_Value", "");
    //52
    request.addProperty("CustomField8_Criteria", "");
    //53
    request.addProperty("CustomField8_Value", "");
    //54
    request.addProperty("CustomField9_Criteria", "");
    //55
    request.addProperty("CustomField9_Value", "");
    //56
    request.addProperty("CustomField10_Criteria", "");
    //57
    request.addProperty("CustomField10_Value", "");

    Log.v("Final Property is",request.toString());




    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = getHttpTransportSE();
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION + methodname, envelope);
        testHttpResponse(ht);
        SoapPrimitive resultsString = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
```

/*changed from orgnal list and for loop

*/
         //   List COOKIE_HEADER = (List) ht.getServiceConnection().getResponseProperties();

```
        data = resultsString.toString();

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception q) {
        q.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}

private final SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapObject request) {
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    //change from orgnl
    //envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes = true;
    envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    return envelope;
}

private final HttpTransportSE getHttpTransportSE() {
    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Proxy.NO_PROXY,MAIN_REQUEST_URL,60000);
    ht.debug = true;
    ht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>");
    return ht;
}
```

}

Comment: Read more about xml parsing and implement, there are many samples out there to help you.

Comment: I have read then but there is a problem it is not converting the data as the data has some uni code symbols such as &lt and &gt , for closing and ending of tag?

Comment: How were we to guess that from the data you posted? Perhaps that should be the detail of your question, rather than the general question you actually asked.  Show us the data that is causing you problems and your code so far.

Comment: oked I am going to edit my question

Comment: Look data closely <before I am going to edit that> there are multiple table in the data that is coming from server , and I have to show it in a grid view to show a these results. Now problem is this table would be a one record/row in my grid table and the next table is going to be a next row in my table So How to do that ?

Comment: That's a completely new question and should be asked as such.  Until you show us your efforts (i.e. code) so far you are unlikely to get any help here. We are not going to write your code for you, but will help you if you have problems with the code you yourself have written to solve your problem.

Comment: oked I am sharing my code but that is simple\